# Is there a way to use block of code from child file to another child file using Django?

Tags: html, django

base.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
  </body>
</html>
```

child1.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% block upperDisplay %}
{% endblock %}
```

child2.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
..code for child2 to base
{% end block%}
```

child11.html (childs for child1):

```
{% extends "child1.html" %}

{% block upperDisplay %}
 ..code for child11 to child1
{ %end block% }
```

Child12:

```
{% extends "child1.html" %}

{% block upperDisplay %}
<div>
  <table>
    .... some code ..
  </table>
  {% block legend %}
  <div>
     .. some code ..
  </div>
  {% end block %}
</div>
{% end block %}
```

Here I wish to use `{% block legend %}` also in child1.html, child11.html.

Can you tell me how to do this Django?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate that in another file and then include it.

**legend_template.html**

```
{% block legend %}
  <div>
     ..some code..
  </div>
{% end block %}
```

Now in other children:

```
{% include "legend_template.html" %}
```